# PGP - Do I share my Public Key or Fingerprint or KeyID?

Tags: gnupg, pgp

I have seen people on Twitter posting a relative short key format. The actual Public Key is very long.

1. What is that they share - Fingerprint or Key ID?
2. How can I identify and Verify that person with just that Key ID? Don't I need the complete public key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You share the public [key](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_(cryptography)), the fingerprint is just a way to make sure someone has your real key. The key ID is an easy way to identify your key, but it's not as unique as the [fingerprint](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public_key_fingerprint) (which is unique to every key).

Usually uploading your public key to a keyserver is good enough, and probably what the people sharing only their fingerprint do. Then anyone can get your key from a keyserver, and you can just share the fingerprint more widely, it would make a decent signature...

You should probably read general info on [Public-key cryptography](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Public-key_cryptography) and [PGP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pretty_Good_Privacy).